# jquery assign tasks to events within anonymous functions

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have three textboxes with same class name and trying to do some custom validations using jquery. With the following codes it pics up the right element and applyes CSS effects if it failed validations. When it comes to removeclass method, every time the class is removed from the last element regardless the focused/clicked element.

```
    txtbox=$(".mintxt");

    txtbox.each(function(){
        txt=$(this);         
        if(txt.val().length<5){
            txt.addClass("er");
            txt.focus(function(){txt.removeClass("er");});
            //noerr=false;
        } 
    });
```

=======================================================================

Final working version

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/oqebyyaq/1)

Comment: Can you create a demo of your situation in jsfiddle.net??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about the `scope`, use `this` element instead of the element which is fetched outside the event handler,

```
txtbox = $(".mintxt");
txtbox.each(function () {
    txt = $(this);
    if (txt.val().length < 5) {
        txt.addClass("er");
        txt.focus(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("er");
        });
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b6fygxgs/)

Answer (score -1):

In order to validate field using Jquery they have to be included in a `<form>`. If so, use [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate the fields you want, and then apply any custom css.

Comment: This is about some custom validation and not about the built in functionalities to the jquery lib. Anyhow thanks for your reply..

Comment: @kumaDK your welcome. My excuses if my answer misguided you. Tried to help you.